# How can i simulate this function using simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have an equation for the speed of a projectile with drag, and I'm trying to simulate it with Simulink. The coefficient c is just all of the terms of the drag equation put together. The function is

```
d2y/dt2 = -9.8 - c(dy/dt)^2
```

My Simulink attempt:

[image: block diagram]